# group or select distinct columns in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table like this

```
records            
columnA columnB columnC columnD
gary    2011    0       a
gary    2011    0       b
gary    2010    1       a
mary    2011    0       a
mary    2010    1       b
mary    2010    1       c
```

i want to parse the table and if i find multiple lines where columnA columnB columnC are common to display the values from these three columns once followed by values found on columnD from each records where those columns A B C where the same.

Something like this

```
print output           
gary    2011    0   a,b
gary    2010    1   a
mary    2011    0   a
mary    2010    1   b,c
```

I am using mysql, I tried with distinct but it duplicates the prints when found similar A B C columns. for example instead of  displaying

```
gary   2011    0   a,b
```

once, it will disaply this line twice and so on three, four ... times, for each similar lines found...

Thank you,
Mozley

Comment: Have you tried `GROUP_CONCAT`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for `GROUP_CONCAT`:

```
SELECT columnA, columnB, columnC,
     GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT columnD
               ORDER BY columnD ASC SEPARATOR ', ') AS columnD
     FROM records
     GROUP BY columnA, columnB, columnC
```

**Result**

```
| COLUMNA | COLUMNB | COLUMNC | COLUMND |
-----------------------------------------
|    gary |    2010 |       1 |       a |
|    gary |    2011 |       0 |    a, b |
|    mary |    2010 |       1 |    b, c |
|    mary |    2011 |       0 |       a |
```

### [See the demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9228d/3)